# Customize SKU in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for a way to customize the SKU in woocommerce. For instance, starts with category ID then subcategory ID, and the 5 digits. I couldn't find any useful article in this field. I found `wc_product_generate_unique_sku` in woocommerce folder, after I make any change the plugin do not work.
Is there any solution for customizing SKU?

Comment: **_"after I make any change the plugin do not work."_** -> This question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.